# Allow registered users to see posts created from the date of sign up onwards

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and I want to allow registered users to only see posts created from their date of sign up onwards.

For example, if the user registered on the 7th of May 2015, he can only see blog entries made from the 7th of May onwards.

From what I understand, the WordPress db does store the date of registration for each user. I'm trying to figure out to code it and where it should go.

Comment: If I registered on a site, I would want to see posts older that when I registered, so I hope your intentions are valid/very good because if that happened on SO or any other site, you'd/I'd be peeved.

Comment: I totally agree with that! It's for a friend of mine and they have a valid reason

Comment: well then this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-old-posts/) may interest you/your friend

Comment: That looks good! But I think that hides all posts regardless of when users registered?

Answer (score 1):

You can start off by using this
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

if you are fairly new to php then wordpress might be a little too difficult. I recommend browsing through wordpresses list of free plugins to see if someone has already made what your looking for. I'm pretty sure you'll find something. https://wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: Thanks! I've had a look at plugins but can't see to find anything that does what I need.